# flutter-mapbox-gl MapBox paints over AppBar and NavBar :(

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-mapbox-gl

I try to get MapBox to work properly in Flutter, but it somehow seems to initially open to big and paint over AppBar and NavBar. After that it seems that it moves into the correct position, but the AppBar and NavBar are now ruined :(

Any way to fix this?

Related Git Issue [here](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1082)

[image]

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-NZ)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

```yaml
environment: 
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  collection:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.3
  get: ^4.6.3
  http:
  logger: ^1.1.0
  mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0
  oauth2_client: ^2.4.0
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.1.57

dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test: 
    sdk: flutter

flutter: 
  uses-material-design: true
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

import '../services/item.dart';

class MapControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapControl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapControlState();
}

class MapControlState extends State<MapControl> {
  final itemService = Get.find<ItemService>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  MapboxMapController? mapController;

  _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  _onStyleLoadedCallback() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: const Text("Style loaded :)"),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: MapboxMap(
          styleString: MapboxStyles.LIGHT,
          accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)),
          onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
        ));
  }
}
```